# wso2esb issue with iterate mediator

Tags: xpath, wso2, esb, mediator, wso2-esb

I'm quite new to WSO2 and XML/XPath and I'm having issues with getting an iterate mediator expression to work. My scenario is the follwing. I'm given a .csv file which is then transformed into XML with the Smooks mediator and a simple XSLT Transformation - both of which work fine, I tested them earlier. They result of this process has the following structure (and is put into a SOAP environment by the esb):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Body>
          <Orderlist xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
              <Order>
                  <Nr>1234</Nr>
                  <Sender>
                      <!-- some child elements here -->>
                  </Sender>
                  <Recipient>
                      <!-- some child elements here -->
                  </Recipient>
              </Order>
              <Order> <!-- same as above --> 
              </Order>
              <!-- more orders here -->
           </Orderlist>
      </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now I'm using the following proxy to perform my transforms and then iterate over the Order elements:

```xml
    <proxy name="Aufgabe3Proxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="https http vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <!-- transformations are done here, producing the above message -->          
      <iterate expression="$body/Orderlist/Order" preservePayload="true">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log level="full"/>
                <send>
                    <property expression="$body/Order/Start/text()"
                        name="uri.var.loc1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <property expression="$body/Order/Ziel/text()"
                        name="uri.var.loc2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <endpoint key="MapsEndpoint"/>
                </send>
            </sequence>
        </target>
      </iterate>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <log level="full"/>
        <aggregate>
            <onComplete expression="//Orderlist">
                 <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport"
                        type="STRING" value="responses-out.xml"/>
                 <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                 <send/>
            </onComplete>
        </aggregate>

    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file://C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Daten\MapsPaare\in</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file://C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Daten\MapsPaare\fail</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file://C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Daten\MapsPaare\out1</parameter>

    </proxy>
```

When I run this and put my .csv into the in-folger, the log only prints the read message and the Outcome of the transformations, but nothing more. Also it doesn't write the Responses-out.xml file (and does not create it).
Can you please point me to the errors I'm making here?

Edit:
A thing I tried out so far is: Since the ESB puts my Orderlist into a namespace, I tried to adjust my Iterate Expression like that:

```xml
<iterate expression="$body/OL:Orderlist/OL:Auftrag" preservePayload="true"
     xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
```

However, when this is run the log gives me an error saying: "SynapseXPath Evaluation of the XPath expression $body/OL:Auftragsliste/OL:Auftrag resulted in an error" and Points out that it's unable to resolve the namespace prefix OL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have a marked answer: the solution was like I wrote in a comment above. Replacing

```
<iterate expression="$body/Orderlist/Order" preservePayload="true">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <property expression="$body/Order/Start/text()"
                    name="uri.var.loc1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="$body/Order/Ziel/text()"
                    name="uri.var.loc2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <endpoint key="MapsEndpoint"/>
            </send>
        </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
```

with

```
<iterate xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" expression="//OL:Orderlist/OL:Order" preservePayload="true">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <property expression="//OL:Order/OL:Start"
                    name="uri.var.loc1" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//OL:Order/OL:Ziel"
                    name="uri.var.loc2" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <endpoint key="MapsEndpoint"/>
            </send>
        </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
```

did fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you tried in your edit is the good way to do. Don't know why the node 'order' become 'Auftrag', but this iterate must work :

```
<iterate expression="$body/OL:Orderlist/OL:Order" preservePayload="true" xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
```

Verify if the error in ESB log don't come from another part of your mediation

Comment: Woops, that's my fault. I thought i'd translate the whole thing for better understanding, must have forgotten it in the edit. 
I just tried <iterate xmlns:OL="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" expression="//OL:Orderlist/OL:Order" sequential="true" preservePayload="true"> which seems to work. This is quiet weird and I don't exactly understand why this works but not the Version with $body.
Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: What happens when I execute this is, that the log in sequence is giving me "empty" messages. They contain nothing but usual the soap-tags enevelope and body as well as an empty orderlist-tag.

Comment: which log give you an empty message : the one inside inSequence/iterate or the one inside outSequence ?

Comment: It was the one inside the sequence in the inSequence's iterate. However, the code was working but my ESB kept deleting the namespace definition inside the iterate bracket that solved the original problem causing XPath to not find any entries/give an exception. Problem is solved now.